# Save ActiveRecord object as an array - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, activerecord

Say I have a class `Foo`. One of `Foo's` columns is called `bars`. I want `bars` to split its `text` contents by `,`, creating an Array. So `"this, to, array"` to `["this","to" ,"array"]`. For some reason, after creating a new instance of `Foo`, `Foo.last.bars` still returns `bars` as `String`. I have a a feeling its my `bars_to_array` method.

I have:

**Foo Class:**

```
class Filter < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def bars_to_array
    bars.split(',')
    save
  end
  ...
end
```

**Foo's Migraiton:**

```
class CreateFoos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :foos do |t|
      ...     
      t.text :bars
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

**foos#create:**

```
def create
  ...
  @foo = Foo.new
  @foo.bars_to_array
  ...
end
```

**EDIT 1:**

I'm aware of `serialize`. I want to split after the initial data gets saved to `bars`.

Comment: Do you actually want to store the data as an array, or just split it after reading it from the column?

Comment: @nPn Thanks for bringing this up. I forgot to mention that I am aware of the `seriazlie` method, but I'm looking to split the text into `array` after saving the object.

Comment: then just move the save __before__ the bars.split(',')

Answer (score 0):

```
class Filter < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :bars, Array
end
```

Comment: would you please care to explain your answer?

Answer (score 0):

The method bars.split(',') does not modify the string, just returns an array. You are discarding the returned array.

Edit:

You can use 'serialize', or you could make two methods:

```
def bars= value
   serialized_bars = value.join(',')
end

def bars
   serialized_bars.split(',')
end

alias_attribute :serialized_bars, :bars
```

Comment: makes sense. How would modify the instance of `Foo` that's being saved then?

Comment: You can use 'serialize', or you could make two methods:
def bars= value
   serialized_bars = value.join(',')
end

def bars
   serialized_bars.split(',')
end

alias_attribute :serialized_bars, :bars

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to accomplish is to have the bars method always just return the string that you store in the text column as an array (split my comma's), then do the following.

Add the following method to your model. This will override the bars method. It will read the actual column, then spit it by comma's and retrun the array.

You don't need your bars_to_array method, the data will be stored as a string but will always be returned as the split array.

```
def bars
  read_attribute(:bars).split(',')
end
```

Comment: I'm playing around with this in the console, doing `Foo.create(bars:"Split this mother")`, then calling `Foo.last.bars_to_array`. `Foo.last.bars` still returns a `String`.

Comment: the bars method will just return the actual column (string).